# Suppose we have a curve $g(x,y)=Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2-1 = 0$, constrained over the unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have a curve $g(x,y)=Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2-1 = 0$, find the maximum and minimum distance of the curve to the origin.

Solution in my textbook (Vector Calculus, 5e James Marsden p.236) that I am mis-understanding:

The problem is equivalent to finding the extreme values of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ subject to the constraining condition $g(x,y) = 0$, Using the Lagrange multiplier method, we have the following equations:

$2x + \lambda(2Ax + 2By) = 0$,

$2y + \lambda(2Bx + 2Cy) = 0$,

$Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 = 1$

Has the author made a mistake here? Should the first two equations not be:

$2x - \lambda(2Ax + 2By) = 0$,

$2y - \lambda(2Bx + 2Cy) = 0$

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of $f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)$ is entirely arbitrary. If I choose to write '$+$' then I might get $\lambda = - 3$. If you chose to write '$-$' for the same problem you would get $\lambda = 3$.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case. Thanks!